# Where is the source for DevTools Network panel filter keywords?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The **filter** text field on the **Network** panel supports various keywords, such as `larger-than` (which only displays files larger than the specified size).

[image: larger-than filter in devtools]

I haven't looked at the DevTools source. Are these defined in a single-file, or distributed throughout the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Chrome Version M50, these filters are defined in a single file - [NetworkLogView.js](https://goo.gl/X5QQp7)

Answer (score 0):

You can find learn more about the filter keywords at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#filter-by-property